# proof theoretic ordinal for Robinson's arithmetic

Tags: logic, ordinal-analysis

Does a theory like Robinson's arithmetic have a proof-theoretic ordinal? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 3):

Well, since $Q$ doesn't even have induction along $\mathbb{N}$, I'm dubious that the notion of proof-theoretic ordinal makes sense for it; but if forced, I'd say the answer has to be $\omega$. Induction along finite orderings is trivial, so $\omega$ is the first ordinal for which it makes sense to ask "Does $Q$ prove induction along this ordinal?," and $Q$ doesn't.

Comment: Well, I guess I was hoping for some ordinal $\alpha$ such that the principlw of transfinite induction up to $\alpha$ plus some minimal theory (e.g., PRA) proves Con(Q).

Comment: @CecilBurrow I believe PRA already proves Con(Q), but I could be wrong. Note that, interestingly, EFA does *not* prove Con(Q) (see section 3 of [this message on the FOM mailing list](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/fom/postings/9912/msg00021.html)); Friedman cites Paris and Wilkie for that.

Comment: I don't know of any proof that PRA proves Con(Q) - a reference would be wonderful!

Comment: @CecilBurrow Hm, I'm having trouble finding a source. Section 3H of [Moschovakis' notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ynm/lectures/lnl.pdf) is where I remember the fact cropping up, but it's not there (although it may still be interesting to you). I'll keep looking . . .

Comment: On the other hand, the proof theoretic ordinal of PRA is $\omega^\omega$, while the proof theoretic ordinal of EFA is just $\omega^3$. So that suggests that PRA proves Con(EFA) and hence Con(Q) . . .

Answer (score 3):

Noah is correct that PRA $\vdash$ Con(Q): On p. 139 of the Handbook of Proof Theory, Chapter 2 (available [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/handbookII/ChapterII.pdf)), Buss shows that $I\Delta_0$ + "tetration is total" $\vdash$ Con($I\Delta_0$), so it certainly proves Con(Q). Since $I\Delta_0 \subseteq$ PRA and PRA proves tetration total, the result follows.

(This is in response to a side question that came up in the comment thread of Noah's answer, but I don't have the karma to post this as a comment).